# Material UI TextField Outline is overflowing on the border

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a textfield in material ui for which  I am using the variant **outlined**. For some reason, it's not showing properly. The label text overflows and when I click on the filed its text cuts from the top on the border. Here is the code

```html
<TextField
  id="outlined-basic"
  label="Statement"
  variant="outlined"
/>
```